# How exactly does the Hibernate @OneToMany annotation work?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I am pretty new to Hibernate and I am studying it on a tutorial. I have some problems understanding how exactly the **OneToMany** annotation works.

So I have these 2 entity classes: **Student** that represents a student and **Guide** that represents a person that guides the student. So each student is associated with a single guide but a single guide can follow more that one student. I want a guide to know the students associated to him.

So I have:

**Student**:

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="enrollment_id", nullable=false)
    private String enrollmentId;    

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name="guide_id")
    private Guide guide;

    public Student() {}
    public Student(String enrollmentId, String name, Guide guide) {
        this.enrollmentId = enrollmentId;
        this.name = name;
        this.guide = guide;
    }

    public Guide getGuide() {
        return guide;
    }
    public void setGuide(Guide guide) {
        this.guide = guide;
    }

}
```

So the **@ManyToOne** annotation on the guide field:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(name="guide_id")
private Guide guide;
```

means that a single guide is associated a single student but a guide can follow many students. Is it right? What exactly does the specified **cascade** settings do? I think it means that when I persist a Student object that contains a **Guide** object as field also this **Guide** object is also automatically persisted. And the same thing happens when I remove a **Student** object, the related **Guide** record is deleted...but I am not absolutely sure about it...

Ok, doing it this way I will have a **mono directional** relationship between a record in the **Student** table and a record in the **Guide** table because in the **Student** table I will have a foreign key to join the **Guide** table so the student can know its guide but, doing it this way, the guide can not know the followed student...and this is not smart.

To do it the **Guide** class is implemented in this way:

```
@Entity
public class Guide {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="staff_id", nullable=false)
    private String staffId; 

    private String name;
    private Integer salary;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="guide", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>(); 

    public Guide() {}
    public Guide(String staffId, String name, Integer salary) {
        this.staffId = staffId;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }   
    public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
        student.setGuide(this);
    }

}
```

So, as you can see, this class contains:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="guide", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();
```

that it is used to declare the bidirectional relationship.

So it seems to me that this annotation automatically create a **guide_id** field into the **Student** table that represent the **foreign key** that implement the bidirectional relation.

In fact using this mapping the **Student** table is automatically created in this way in my database:

```
'id', 'bigint(20)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'enrollment_id', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'name', 'varchar(255)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'guide_id', 'bigint(20)', 'YES', 'MUL', NULL, ''
```

So in the **Student** entity class I have not defined the **guide_id** field but I have it in the **Student** table on the database. So I think that the creation of this field in the table depends on the previous **@OneToMany** annotation defined in the **Guide** entity class. Is that correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can define a `@OneToMany` entity without a bidirectional association, and the added column is on the `Many` entity side in the database (even though the entity doesn't know it is linked to the `One`-side entity).

You can also use a join table for this, but it's not necessary.