# Hibernate not creating one of the columns in my table

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get hibernate to auto create my tables using :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Everything is working except that one of the columns on one of my tables is being ignored by Hibernate and I can't figure out why... Here is the code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "boat_id", nullable = false)
    private List<Boat> boats;

}
```

The id and customer fields are being created but not the boats field.

```
Hibernate: create table orders (id int4 not null, customer_id int4 not null, primary key (id))
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't have multiple id's of Boats (it's a List!) in the orders table. If the Boat can only be in one Order, then it should be joined by the order_id in Boat. In Order use `mappedBy` in `One To Many`

Comment: @Turo, So I can't have a list of multiple boat ids? In my app, one order can have one or more boats. Are you saying I should instead make it a many to one in the boats?

Comment: What @Turo is trying to tell you is that you cannot store multiple values in a single database column. What type did you expect for the `boats` column to have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How exactly does the Hibernate @OneToMany annotation work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338309/how-exactly-does-the-hibernate-onetomany-annotation-work)

Comment: You can have a list of Boats in Order.Look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many).

Comment: I'll read up on those links, thanks!